# Azure function deployed but not running

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019, kudu

I have a project configured to publish an Azure function app from Visual Studio. It has worked reliably, at least for editing existing functions. Recently, I added a new function to the project and published it – no changes to the app configuration were made. When I open the function app in the Azure portal, the new function isn't there. If I go to the app's Kudu site, the new function has a folder in wwwroot just like the others, with a function.json file, and the deployment is logged. There are no output logs for the new function, however, and it is clear that it isn't running.

Playing around with it, I've noticed that even changes to the functions that do appear in the portal are not being applied. Has anyone else experienced this before? How do I fix the apparent disconnect?

Comment: Which version of function you are using?

Comment: I'm using runtime version ~3 (3.0.13139.0). That said, I've noticed that my host.json file has 'version' as 2.0, though I'm not sure this is referring to the same thing. I haven't explicitly targeted a runtime version in the local.settings.json file.

Comment: @BowmanZhu I'm also getting a warning on the Function App Settings blade that reads: "Cannot Upgrade with Existing Functions", if that might be relevant

Comment: In fact, all of the thing you offer is normal. They should not cause thia problem.

Comment: Can you try to deploy your code in new function instance on Azure?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Yes, it works deploying to a new function app.

Comment: It seems a bug.

Comment: It is a bug. You can try to deploy your code in new function instance on Azure and it should work.

Comment: I posted an answer, can you [mark it as the answer](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png) to this question to end it? This will help others find the way out.:)